# Reference view to app delegate using storyboards

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I am trying to create a UITableView using storyboard but I came to something that at the end may be easy but I have no idea how to solve it.
First of all let me point out that I know that one of the limitations of storyboards is that you will have to dig through the storyboard to find information about a view you have and link it to the app delegate.
I have create my mutable array and the information that I will use in the table in the app delegate and now I want to reference that UITableView to the app delegate. The hierarchy goes like that

1. First I have the root view that once you click on a button it will redirect you to the second view
2. Inside the second view there is another button that once you press it it will redirect you to the UINavigationController
3. The UINavigationController contains the UITableView.

Therefore as you can see there are two views before the navigation control and the UITableView.

Here is the code I am trying to use but it does not work

```
UIViewController *viewController = (UIViewController *)self.window.rootviewController;

// The next line refers to the second view but does not work at all
UIViewController *secondView = [[UIViewController viewController] objectAtIndex:1];

//Then the following line is to redirect from the second view to the navigation controller
UINavigationController *navigationController =[[secondView viewController] objectAtIndex:0];

//Then is the table view
BuildingsViewController *buildingsViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
```

The above code does not work. Can anyone please help me?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this code is in the app delegate there are a variety of reasons why it will probably not work.  Firstly you appear to be mixing up View's, ViewControllers and Navigation controllers with what you are trying to do.  Secondly there is no guarantee at the time you are trying to do this that all of the views/viewcontrollers have yet been created yet or are joined in the way they will be when the final building view controller is rendered.

What you could try instead is in your BuildingsViewController (which you say is your table view controller) you can get a handle to the App Delegate by using

```
MyAppDelegate *myAppDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate
```

Once you have a handle to the delegate you can simply reference your mutable array structure etc. that you created on it from within your BuildingsViewController.

e.g. in the 'numberOfRowsInSection' method:

```
MyAppDelegate *myAppDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate
NSMutableArray *myBuildings = myAppDelegate.buildingArray;
return [myBuildings count];
```

Or in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
// something like this but using your names for app delegate, building array and the accessor for the building name
MyAppDelegate *myAppDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate
NSMutableArray *myBuildings = myAppDelegate.buildingArray;

cell.textLabel.text = [myBuildings objectAtIndex indexPath.row].theBuildingName;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.
I did what you have said and works only for the numberOfRowsInSection. For the cellForRowAtIndexPath there are a number of errors and does not work at all

Comment: What part doesn't work?  The key point was demonstrating how to get access to the array containing your table model data from within the table view controller via the singleton accessor on the app to get to the app delegate.